# bootstrap taking extra margin on left for span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add Div and Div which comes at bottom has extra margin on 4th span.

4th Span comes at bottom but is not properly aligned. It has more left-padding than above one.

[image: Span4]

here are my code :-

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class=span12>
        <div class=span4>
            <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another `<div class="row"></div` in there, like below:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class=span12>
    <div class="row"> <!-- Additional row HERE -->
    <div class=span4>
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=span12>
    <div class="row">  <!-- Additional row HERE -->
    <div class="span4">
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not what i want to do.. i just want to use span4 and i want it to auto-aligned :(

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution is

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class=span12>
    <div class=span4>
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class=span12>
    <div class="span4">
        <div style="background: url(img/background.jpg) center no-repeat">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this because you complete the grid with 3 span4, in other words, 3*span4 = 12
then, you need create a new div container with span12 and inside of this div you can add new spanN until complete the 12 grid
you got it? :)

Comment: i dont want to use span12 after every 3 span4

Comment: sorry, is the only way you can do that.
or maybe you need

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">...</div>
      <div class="span3">...</div>
      <div class="span3">...</div>
      <div class="span3">...</div>
    </div>

because, if you use span4, the grid is full width 3 of them.